# Drawing custom shape with MetaUML

Tags: graphics, metauml

How to draw image like this:

[image]

I use MetaUML package for drawing Uml.

Can it be used to draw this image? I want to keep my image styles uniform and don't want to use other drawing package just for one image.

I can draw it like this:

[image]

but how can I get rid of the Component icon? And how to make boxes same dimension?

This is the code I use

```
input metauml;
beginfig(1);

    Class.A("Entity")()();
    A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
    A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;
    A.info.iMethodStack.top := 0;
    A.info.iMethodStack.bottom := 0;

    Class.B("Render")()();
    B.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
    B.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;
    B.info.iMethodStack.top := 0;
    B.info.iMethodStack.bottom := 0;

    Class.C("Collectable")()();
    C.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
    C.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;
    C.info.iMethodStack.top := 0;
    C.info.iMethodStack.bottom := 0;

    Component.BigC("Spoon")(A, B, C);

    leftToRight(10)(A, B, C);

    drawObject(BigC);

endfig;
end
```

**edit**
I can get rid of component symbol by using `Package` instead of `Component`, but result looks a lot different than original image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MetaUML does not provide any easy way to control the width of your classes, but you can get them looking close to what you want with the built in "ClassName" function.  And you can get rid of the stereotype in the Component by redefining the macro that draws it to do nothing.  Like this:

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate:="uml%c.eps";

input metauml;
vardef drawComponentVisualStereotype(text ne)= relax enddef;

beginfig(1);
     ClassName.A("Entity");
     ClassName.B("Render");
     ClassName.C("Collectable");
     Component.BigC("Spoon")(A, B, C);
     leftToRight(10)(A, B, C);
     drawObject(BigC);
endfig;
```

which produces this: [image]

If you only want to suppress the visual stereotype in this one figure, then move the re-definition inside the `beginfig` / `endfig` scope.

If you were not already committed to MetaUML, you could consider using good old `boxes.mp` that comes with Metapost as standard.  Here's an example of what you could do with it (designed to continue the above file).

```
input boxes;
verbatimtex \font\sf=phvr8r\sf etex

beginfig(2);
    boxit.bA(btex \strut Entity etex);
    boxit.bB(btex \strut Render etex);
    boxit.bC(btex \strut Collectable etex);
    boxit.bS(btex \vrule width 0pt depth 40pt Spoon etex);

    % make the class boxes the same size
    forsuffixes $=bA,bB,bC:$.ne-$.sw = (60,30); endfor

    bA.c = bB.c + 80 left;
    bC.c = bB.c + 80 right;
    bS.c = bB.n; 
    bS.sw = bA.sw - (10,10);

    forsuffixes $=bA,bB,bC: fill bpath.$ withcolor .88white; endfor
    drawboxed(bA,bB,bC,bS);
endfig;
end.
```

which gives you this: [image]

Note that `boxit` tries hard to center the text contents horizontally and vertically, so one way to offset the text is to use an invisible rule sticking down as I have done here in the "Spoon" box.

Comment: Thank you! It looked it is wouldn't be answered. Once again, thank you!